# Get status job in cdsw

Tags: cloudera, cdsw

I have some R and python scripts in CDSW "Cloudera-Data-Science-Workbench".  I create a shell script to run this with `curl -v -XPOST`.

How to get the status of a job from the API CDSW?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's been a while since this question was posted but hopefully the answer can still be useful to someone :)

After you run:

`curl -v -XPOST http://cdsw.example.com/api/v1/projects/<$USERNAME>/<$PROJECT_NAME>/jobs/<$JOB_ID>/start --user "API_KEY:" --header "Content-type: application/json"`

You should be able to see in the output a URL that looks like this:

`http://cdsw.example.com/api/v1/projects/<$USERNAME>/<$PROJECT_NAME>/dashboards/<$ID>`

So then you can use it to retrieve the job status for example with piping the status using `jq` (or without it so you can also see the status in the output as well as other stuff returned):

`curl -v http://cdsw.example.com/api/v1/projects/<$USERNAME>/<$PROJECT_NAME>/dashboards/<$ID> --user "API_KEY:" | jq '.status'`